# Finding all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x+1| + |x-1| < 4$

Tags: calculus, inequality, solution-verification

We want to find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with

$$|x+1| + |x-1| < 4$$

I tried the following, but I'm uncertain if this is correct:

Critical points: $x= -3$ and $x = 1$.

**Case** $1$:

$$x \in (-\infty, -3) \\ 
|x+1| = -(x+1) = -x-1 \\
|x-1| = -(x-1) = -x+1 \\
|x+1| + |x-1| < 4\\
\iff -x-1-x+1 < 4\\
\iff -2x < 4 \\
\iff x < -2 \\ \Rightarrow  \text{ holds } \forall x \in (-\infty,-2[$$

**Case** $2$:

$$x \in [-3, 1) \\ 
|x+1| + |x-1| < 4\\
\iff -x-1-x+1 < 4\\
\iff -2x < 4 \\
\iff x < -2 \\ \Rightarrow  \text{ holds } \forall x \in [-3,-2[$$

**Case** $3$:

$$x \in (1, \infty) \\ 
|x+1| = x+1 \\
|x-1| = x-1 \\
x+1+x-1 < 4\\
\iff 2x < 4 \\
\iff x < 2 \\ \Rightarrow  \text{ holds } \forall x \in [1,2)$$

The solution would then be $x \in (-\infty,-2) \cup [1,2)$.

Is this correct/wrong? Is this the common approach for questions like these?

Comment: Why don't you draw the graph of the function $f(x)=|x+1|+|x-1|$ and check your self wether it's correct or not ?

Comment: @Surb On Desmos it shows that $x \in [-2,2]$. So my solution is wrong, but what is wrong with the approach?

Comment: One thing that's wrong with this approach is that it violates common sense: Can the quantity $|x+1|+|x-1|$ really be $<4$ when $x$ is close to $-\infty$? Let's test it out when $x = -10000$: $$|(-10000)+1| + |(-10000)-1|  = 9999 + 10001 = 20000 \not< 4$$ You can discover your own logical error by walking through your case 1 proof, step by step, but inserting the specific value $x=-10000$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sol 1)

[image]

This image shows the graph of $y=|x+1|+|x-1|$ and $y=4$.

From this graph, we can easily get the answer: $x \in (-2, 2).$

Sol 2)

***Case 1.*** $x < -1.$

$|x-1|+|x+1|=1-x-x-1=-2x < 4.$

$\therefore \;-2 < x < -1.$

---

***Case 2.*** $-1 \leq x \leq 1.$

$|x-1|+|x+1|=1-x+x+1<4.$

$\therefore \; -1 \leq x \leq 1. $

---

***Case 3.*** $1 <x. $

$|x-1|+|x+1| = 2x < 4, x < 2.$

$\therefore 1<x<2.$

---

$\therefore x \in (-2, 2).$

Comment: How do you get to the cases? Also, where did you plot the graph? I plotted $\left|x+1\right|+\left|x-1\right|\ <4$ on https://www.desmos.com/calculator?lang=de and it looks different than yours

Comment: @mathisdifficult Alright, my first graph is about two graphs: $f(x)=|x-1|+|x+1|$ and $g(x)=4$. Also, the gray one stands for $f(x)<g(x).$ If you put $|x+1|+|x-1|<4$, you'll have the same graph with the gray one above. Second, I divided the cases to 3: $-1>x, 1\geq x\geq -1, x>1.$ This gets us $-2<x<2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a cord of length $4$ with ends attached to the points $-1$ and $1.$ When the cord is maximaly extended to the right or left it reaches the points $2$ and $-2,$ respectively. Therefore the answer is $(-2,2).$

Similarly let the cord of length $2L$ be attached to the points $a<b$ such that $2L>b-a.$ Then the solution of
$$|x-a|+|x-b|<2L$$
is $(-L+{a+b\over 2}, L+{a+b\over 2}).$