# Finding all $x$ which fulfill $|x| \leq |x+1| $

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-explanation

We want to find all $x$ which fulfill
$$|x| \leq |x+1| \text{ (*)}$$

If we plot the graph we already know that $x \in [-\frac{1}{2}, \infty)$.

What I don't understand is the approach in the solution.

We take the critical points $\{0,-1\}$ and look at each case:

Case $1$: $x \in (-\infty,-1] $
$$|x| = -x \\
|x+1| = -(x+1) = -x+1 \\
(*)\Leftrightarrow -x \leq -x-1 \\
\Leftrightarrow 0 \leq -1 \Rightarrow \text{does not work for } x \in (-\infty,1)
$$

Case $2$: $x \in [-1,0]$
$$|x| = -x \\
|x+1| = x+1 \\
(*) \Leftrightarrow -x \leq x+1 \\
\Leftrightarrow -\frac{1}{2} \leq x \text{ holds } \forall x \in [- \frac{1}{2},0]$$

Case $3$: $x \in [0, \infty]$
$$|x| = x \\
|x+1| = x+1 \\
(*) \Leftrightarrow x \leq x+1 \\
\Leftrightarrow 0 \leq 1 \text{ holds } \forall x \in [0, \infty)$$

Thus, the solution is $[- \frac{1}{2}, \infty)$

**Question** $1$:
Why is $0$ a critical point? $|0| \leq |0 +1| = 0 \leq 1$. Aren't critical points values where the inequality becomes $0$?

**Question** $2$:
Why is $|x| = -x$ in case $1$ and $2$? And why do we rewrite $|x+1| $ as $-x +1$? Wouldn't any negative value become positive because $|x|$ is an absolute value?

**Question** $3$: I tried the same approach in this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4543030/finding-all-x-in-mathbbr-with-x1-x-1-4), but it already failed at case $1$. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1**: The critical points are where one of the absolute values is $0$ because the sign changes there. That's $0$ and $-1$ here.

**Q2**: In case 1 and 2 we have $x \leq 0$. Since
$$|x| = \begin{cases} x & \text{for } x \geq 0,\\ -x & \text{for } x \leq 0, \end{cases}$$
we have $|x| = -x$ in these cases. Note that $-x$ is indeed positive if $x < 0$. For the same reason we have $|x+1| = -(x+1)$ if $x \leq -1$.

**Q3**: I think you already got a great answer there. You got it wrong because you took the wrong points for your case analysis.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand what you mean with your reply to Q$1$ though ("sign changes"). Can you please give me an example?

Comment: @mathisdifficult Sorry, I made a typo. $|x|$ is $0$ at $x = 0$ and $|x+1|$ is $0$ at $x = -1$. Similarly, in your linked question, $|x-1|$ is $0$ at $x = 1$.

Comment: So the critical points in the other question should have been $-1$ and $1$?

Comment: @mathisdifficult Yes.

Comment: But if we take the critical point $-1$ there, we would also have concluded that it holds $\forall x \in (-\infty, -1[$ which is wrong. If I were to use the same approach we use in this question here with the inequality given in the other question, it wouldn't work. Can you apply the approach of this thread here onto the other inequality please? I'm really stuck understanding the "algorithm" or the steps behind finding the solution.

Comment: @mathisdifficult You still need to check the different cases, the critical points only determine which cases to consider. It does not mean that the whole interval is in. In the other question, in the case $x \in (-\infty,-1]$, you need to solve $-(x+1)-(x-1) < 4$, which is equivalent to $-2x < 4$, which is true for $x > -2$. Thus $(-\infty,-1] \cap (-2,\infty) = (-2,-1]$ is in. Then you continue with the other cases.